# sort -n does not work

Tags: bash, sorting, alphabetical

I have a file and I want it alphabetically sorted:

```
cat file
peptide9
peptide89
peptide99
peptide79
peptide4
peptide58
peptide990
```

and when I use

```
cat file | sort -n
```

the result is:

```
peptide4
peptide58
peptide79
peptide89
peptide9
peptide99
peptide990
```

I tried different options of sort, but the result is always the same!
The output I want is

```
peptide4
peptide9
peptide58
peptide79
peptide89
peptide99
peptide990
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `--version-sort` (`-V`):

```
$> sort --version-sort t
peptide4
peptide9
peptide58
peptide79
peptide89
peptide99
peptide990
```

An alternative would be, "use 'e' as delimiter, sort the 3 column as number":

```
$> sort -te -k3 -n t
peptide4
peptide9
peptide58
peptide79
peptide89
peptide99
peptide990
```

Comment: Note that version won't work for negative numbers

Answer (score 3):

Sort numerically, with the key starting at the 8th character of the 1st
field:

```
sort -n -k1.8 file
```

Sort with that key, treating it as a number, but not other fields
(useful if you *have* other fields):

```
sort -k1.8n file
```

`info sort` for more details.